# How do i use an AutoPostback functionality for a radsearchbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, autopostback, search-box

By default, some of the telerik radcontrols are having autopostback option, but for radsearchbox, the auto postback functionality was not available, is it possible to  achieve that in code?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the radsearchbox is not having that option, but you can use normal asp.net `textbox` control with `OnTextChanged` event for postbacking the server.

Better raise a ticket in telerik forum.